# Convert RGB Colour to OLE_Color

Tags: .net, colors, ole, rgb

I have the unenviable task of maintaining an ActiveX control that expects OLE_Colors as the back/for colour of the control.

Is there a tool or a .NET code sample that will convert from an RGB colour (or a hex colour) to an OLE_Color?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle()